# How to fix "No gene can be mapped, Expected input gene ID, return NULL..." error in clusterProfiler?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying EnrichKEGG on a few gene samples of genes to check it works before inputting the full genome:
This is my data input as test.csv

| id | fc |
| --- | --- |
| AJAP_14870 | -0.04 |
| AJAP_14875 | 0.32 |
| AJAP_14880 | -0.06 |
| AJAP_14885 | 0.15 |
| AJAP_14890 | -0.52 |
| AJAP_14895 | -0.39 |
| AJAP_14900 | 0.16 |

````
> geneList = test[,2]
> names(geneList) = as.character(test[,1])
> geneList = sort(geneList, decreasing = TRUE)


> mygene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
> 
> kk <- enrichKEGG(gene         = mygene,
+                  organism     = 'aja',
+                  pvalueCutoff = 0.05)```
````

There are no spaces in the gene names, I tested via

````
print(head(test$ID), quote=TRUE)```
````

But I get the error

````
--> No gene can be mapped....
--> Expected input gene ID:
--> return NULL...```
````

I also tried installing through other means

```
> getOption("clusterProfiler.download.method")
#[1] "libcurl"
> install.packages("R.utils")
> library(R.utils)
> R.utils::setOption("clusterProfiler.download.method","auto")
```

but that gives me the same error when I run the code?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What organism is 'aja'? Would enrichKEGG have a database for 'aja' genes? Does your code work if you use `organism = 'mmu'`? I think this type of question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response. I have previously got this code to work and now its just throwing out the error in the post?

> search_kegg_organism('aja', by = "kegg_code")
     kegg_code        scientific_name            common_name
5760       aja Amycolatopsis japonica Amycolatopsis japonica

Thanks for the advice, I'll post there :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21654/how-to-fix-no-gene-can-be-mapped-expected-input-gene-id-return-null-error

Comment: @jared_mamrot No worries, thank you! :)